# is a nested class a singleton in java

Tags: java, singleton, inner-classes, nested-class

In Java a nested class is an inner class that is declared static. E.g.:

```
class Basic{

   public static class NestedClass{};
}
```

I am wondering if a nested class is a singleton by default, or if I may create a list of instances such as

```
class Basic{

   public static NestedClass{};

   List<NestedClass> items;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a singletone is?

Comment: Your terminology about "nested classes" etc. is incorrect — see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html: "Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a singleton (where did you get that idea?). Apart from the fact that it's a [static nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) (and that does *not* imply that it's a singleton), it's a normal class as any other - in particular, you can create as many different instances of `NestedClass` as you want. If you need it to *be* a singleton, then you'll have to explicitly code it yourself.

Comment: It's a static nested class. It isn't an inner class. Inner and static are mutually exclusive.

Comment: You are funny asking where did I get the idea from: that's the whole point of my question: I am wondering if one implies the other. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @CoteMounyo Everyone else is wondering the same thing. It's a perfectly good question, and you haven't answered it. Where *did* you get the idea? It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

> In Java a nested class is an inner class that is declared static.

No. In Java an [*inner* class is a *nested* class that is *not* explicitly or implicitly declared `static.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) JLS #8.1.3. You have this back to front.

> I am wondering if a nested class is a singleton by default

No.

Nesting, static, and inner have nothing to do with singletons.